# while extracting data from JSON format using python

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON output.

```
{
    "data": {
        "BaselineLastFinish": "N/A",
        "BlockSchedStart": "N/A",
        "BlockSchedStop": "N/A",
        "CurrentCycleDay0": "Tue, 17 Apr 2016 00:00:00 GMT",
        "CurrentCycleSchedMaint": "N/A",
        "LastReboot": "Tue, 06 Oct 2015 20:46:16 +0000",
        "LastRunFailCount": "0",
        "LastRunStatus": "No Results",
        "LastRunSuccessCount": "0",
        "MaintInProgress": "False",
        "NextCycleDay0": "Tue, 19 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT",
        "NextCycleSchedMaint": "N/A",
        "PPID": null,
        "PatchProfile": "",
        "PreviousCycleDay0": "Tue, 18 Mar 2016 00:00:00 GMT",
        "PreviousCycleSchedMaint": "N/A",
        "row": "CH1||N/A|N/A|N/A||0|0|False|Tue, 08 Oct 2015 20:46:16 +0000",
        "servername": "CH1"
    },
    "message": "OK",
    "status": "success",
    "status_code": "200",
    "timestamp": "2016-04-26 08:43:44",
    "uuid": "3533etetetet"
}
```

I am trying to extract LastReboot from the above JSON output. I am trying it in below manner but without luck.

```
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
data = json.loads(response.text)
print data['LastReboot']
```

I am getting below error::

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "atp.py", line 16, in <module>
    print data['LastReboot']
KeyError: 'LastReboot'
```

Comment: try `data['data']['LastReboot']`

Comment: you have to first call 'data' like this data['data']['LastReboot']

Comment: Thanks All. It fixed my problem.Awsome...cheers to you guys.

Answer (score 3):

first you have to call 'data', like here:

```
data['data']['LastReboot']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `data` key, try the following

```
>>>data['data']['LastReboot']
"Tue, 06 Oct 2015 20:46:16 +0000"
```